# Long words don't float, are they denser than short words?

Tags: css

I want some text to be displayed within a box.

So, I wrap my text with an `<article>` tag

```
<article>
    <p>Here is my text ready to be boxed.</p>
</article>
```

and style it as a fixed width block, make long words to break, and hide the text when overflow:

```
article {
   display: inline-block;
   width:160px;
   overflow: hidden;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

so far, so good. Text wraps correctly and long words break and wrap.

Problem happens when I put a floating image in front of the text.

```
<article>
    <img src="img.png"></img>
    <p>Here is my text, now preceded by an image.</p>
</article>
```

conveniently styled to float before the text.

```
img {
   width: 32px;
   float: left;
}
```

When text has only short words, it floats and wraps correctly. But long words don't float anymore, they sink to the bottom of the image.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s0pvgoqu/23/

Are long words denser than short?

---

**EDIT** I am editing my question to include some complementary information to the answer I have accepted.

It seems that the only way to solve this problem is to break the long words with `<wbr>` trags.

Here is my code to insert `<wbr>` tags in long words

```
/* insert word break hint tags in long words at num pos */
String.prototype.wbr = function(num) {  
  return this.replace(
    RegExp("(\\w{" + num + "})(\\w)", "g"), 
    function(match,submatch1,submatch2){return submatch1 + "<wbr>" +submatch2}
  );
}
```

Comment: Dunno what causes the behaviour but you can use `<wbr>` to hint word-breaks, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs. After several attempts with styling and container creation, I am implementing a simple `<wbr>` insertion function. Transform your comment into an answer and I will upvote and accept it.

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll: Never knew about `<wbr>`, very handy! @PA.: Can you update your question or add a comment with the `<wbr>` insertion function you come up with?

Comment: @MikeCovington, let's give some time to Szabolcs to answer, if not, I will answer myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I came in to my mind is to use **`<wbr>`** to hint word-breaks.

This of course not a CSS solution thus might not be suitable in every situation, but it works well with floated content as well.

Comment: @PA. Thanks for waiting. If it's not secret I'd be interested in that insertion script, and probably others arriving here might find it useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add word-break: break-all;

```
article {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:12px;
    margin:2px;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    background-color:#eee;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: yep, good idea, it fixes floating of long words, but breaks short words, which, in my case, is worse as it impairs too much legibility.

Comment: this will cause short words to break as well, not really optimal.